# Having trouble accessing an array of objects through pointers

Tags: c++

I am working on program that contains a Movie class in which lies a title, criticRating, and an audienceRating. I have a static array and am creating a function called PrintMovies that will print out the array of Movies into a nice table. I am having trouble accessing other elements besides the first element in the array to print out to the table.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::setw;

struct Movie {
    std::string title;
    int criticRating; // from 0 to 100
    int audienceRating; // from 0 to 100

    Movie(string t, int c, int a) {
        title = t;
        criticRating = c;
        audienceRating = a;
    }

    Movie() {                       // Default constructor
        title = "DEFAULT TITLE";
        criticRating = 0;
        audienceRating = 0;
    }


};

void PrintMovies(Movie* movies, int numMovies) {

    cout << "Movies" << endl;
    cout << "Critic    Audience    Title" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numMovies; i++) {
        cout << setw(6) << (movies->criticRating) << setw(12) << (movies->audienceRating) << "    " << (movies->title) << endl;
    }

}

int main() {

    Movie TenMovies[10] = { Movie("Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",92,90),
        Movie("Deadpool",83,95), Movie("Donnie Darko",85,80),
        Movie("2001: A Space Odyssey",96,89), Movie("Spaceballs",54,83),
        Movie("The Matrix",87,85), Movie("Inception",86,91),
        Movie("The Martian",92,92), Movie("Toy Story",100,92),
        Movie("Monty Python and the Holy Grail",97,95) };

    PrintMovies(TenMovies, 10);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to think about this is like a c-style string.

If you want to print an individual character, you would do something like this -

```
char *myStr = "Hello world!";
std::cout << myStr[1] << std::endl;
```

You guessed it, that would print 'e', since 'e' has an index of 1.

Now what happens if you say this (notice the de-reference *) -

`std::cout << *myStr << std::endl;`

That would print 'H'. That's because H is at the beginning of the array, and whenever you create a new array, the address of that array/pointer is of the first element.

Check this out -

```
0x4050e0 H
0x4050e1 e
0x4050e2 l
0x4050e3 l
0x4050e4 o
0x4050e5
0x4050e6 w
0x4050e7 o
0x4050e8 r
0x4050e9 l
0x4050ea d
0x4050eb !
0x4050ec
```

This is an example of what the string might look like in memory at different addresses.

myStr's address is at 0x4050e0, same as H! If you were to say myStr++ that would move the address to e, or 0x4050e1.
Example -

```
char *myStr = "Hello world!";
myStr++;
std::cout << myStr << std::endl;
```

That would print "ello world!" instead of "Hello world!", since we incremented the pointer. Pointers point to locations (or addresses) in memory, therefore to increment one moves you to the next address.

With that said, there's multiple ways to do this.

One is like accessing single characters in a c-style string, using your i loop variable as the array index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numMovies; i++) {
    cout << setw(6) << (movies[i].criticRating) << setw(12) << (movies[i].audienceRating) << "    " << (movies[i].title) << endl;
}
```

Otherwise you could do it this way, and it lets you see why pointers are called pointers :

```
for (int i = 0; i < numMovies; i++) {
    cout << setw(6) << (movies->criticRating) << setw(12) << (movies->audienceRating) << "    " << (movies->title) << endl;

    //Increment movies' address to the next Movie in memory.
    movies++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a field "criticRating" in item #i of an array of objects "movies", use the following syntax:

```
 movies[i].criticRating
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << setw(6) << ((*(movies + i)).criticRating) << setw(12) << ((*(movies + i)).audienceRating) << "    " << ((*(movies + i)).title) << endl;**You are using array for not travesring with array of Movies use this syntax**
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you guys so much for all the quick answers!! I guess some of the stuff I was trying before didn't have proper parentheses... I got to test a lot of these solutions and they all worked great! Thanks again all